# TypeScript: What’s the use of placeholder <P> after a function?

Tags: typescript

I have a simple function like below:

```
function functionName<T>(parameters: U): V {
    // Function body
}
```

I don't understand why we need `<T>` here.

Will the below not work, because we want to just mention the argument type and the return type of the function?

```
function functionName(parameters: U): V {
    // Function body
}
```

Comment: If your function is really as simple as you say, indeed the `T` generic type parameter is useless, like an unused function parameter could be.

Comment: Normally such generic type argument is used to constrain function parameters and/or the return type. When applied on parameters, TS can try inferring the generic type from usage.

Answer (score -1):

In TypeScript, when you see  in a function signature, it indicates that the function is using generics. Generics allow you to create functions, classes, or interfaces that work with any data type, providing flexibility and type safety. Let's break down your example and then provide another example to illustrate generics further.

Original Function:

```js
function functionName<T>(parameters: U): V {
    // Function body
}
```

Explaination:

```js
function functionName<TypeParam>(parameters: ParamType): ReturnType {
    // Function body
}
```

Full Example:

```js
function getFirstElement<T>(arr: T[]): T | undefined {
    return arr.length > 0 ? arr[0] : undefined;
}

// Example usage:
const firstElement = getFirstElement<number[]>([1, 2, 3]); // firstElement is of type number | undefined
const firstString = getFirstElement<string[]>(["a", "b", "c"]); // firstString is of type string | undefined
```

Comment: getFirstElement  you are using all T can you show me an example with all different i.e
`function getFirstElement<T>(arr: U[]): V | undefined`

Comment: This answer looks AI generated. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: @DavidW: A contraindication is that *[explanation](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=Explaination)* is misspelt. It could have been manually postprocessed.

Answer (score -3):

I found some explanation from the https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

is just like a variable.

[image]

Comment: Screenshots of text are not appropriate for Stack Overflow. Could you please work on presenting this information in a way accessible for all readers?